# Getting JMS headers on Spring Integration

Tags: header, jms, spring-integration

How do I get JMS headers on my spring integration jms inbound channel ? I have not found much information on the reference.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [DefaultJmsHeaderMapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/jms/DefaultJmsHeaderMapper.html) class. It is responsible (by default) for mapping to and from JMS messages into Spring Integration messages. Once you define appropriate rules, JMS message headers will be visible as any other SI message headers (message.getHeaders()).

Comment: I got this. But how do I plug it on my inbound channel ? Using only XML configuration?

Comment: You don't plug it into channel but into inbound channel adapter. If you use jms:message-driven-channel-adapter just set its header-mapper attribute in the XML.